# Python Lambda if statements

Tags: python, list, if-statement, lambda

I'm trying to make a list of the number of days corresponding to months and I need to account for leap years and I want to be able to access either 28 days or 29 days depending on if it's a leap year. This is what I have:

```
def code(x)
    monthdays = [31, lambda x: 28 if leapyear(x) == False else 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    return months[1]
```

leapyear() is just a function with 1 parameter that returns True if it is a leapyear and False otherwise. For some reason that won't return the number I want. How else can I do this?

Comment: Just delete `lambda x:`. And where is `months` coming from?

Comment: Perhaps, it set's x to 28 when there is no leap year (from what I am getting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `lambda` here (and anyway you're not *calling* it), a simple conditional expression will do the trick. Try this:

```
monthdays = [31, 29 if leapyear(x) else 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

Also, I believe that in the last line you meant this:

```
return monthdays[1]
```

…Otherwise what's the point of creating `monthdays` if we're not going to use it? Even more, why create a whole list if we're interested in a single position?

Comment: Thanks! and sorry, I was in kind of a rush when I asked my question and didn't pay attention to my variable name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be precise about what is a leap year and calendar events it is recommended to use [`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange). You can use it like this:

```
from calendar import monthrange

year = 2015
days = []
for month in range(1,13):
    days.append(monthrange(year, month)[1])

print(days)
```

which returns a list containing the number of days for each month of a given year:

```
[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

and if you just want Feb's number of days you can just calculate that:

```
from calendar import monthrange

year = 2015
feb_days = monthrange(year, 2)[1]
print(feb_days)
```